# How to hide skipped items when iterating over a loop in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

In an Ansible playbook i iterate over a list in a loop. The task is formatted as follows:

```yaml
- name: Task
  command: 'bash -c "curl -k -X GET https://{{ item.host }}:{{ intem.port }}/{{ item_name }}"'
  when: 'item_name == item.item_list_name and item_name not in ("item1","item2"...)'
  loop:
    - { host: '{{ variableA }}', port: '{{ variableB }}', item_list_name : {{ item_name }} }
  register: out
  failed_when: 'out.rc != 0' 
  ignore_errors: true
```

While this playbook is *functional* , it's not pretty.
When running the task, it iterates through the list, but it prints all output, even for the cases where it's false.

I would like to:

- Clean the output so it prints only the result of the item that is not skipped

Some other improvements I need to make, but I think I can manage is to move the list in the variables file.

Other than building the playbook as is, nothing because I have no idea how.

Answer (score 0):

> Clean the output so it prints only the result of the item that is not skipped

Create an ansible.cfg, w this content:

```ini
[defaults]
display_skipped_hosts = False
```

Comment: According [Ansible Configuration Settings - `DISPLAY_SKIPPED_HOSTS`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#display-skipped-hosts), that's just the default setting. It would need to be `False` and in order to suppress "_displaying skipped task/host entries in a task in the default callback_".

Answer (score 0):

> ***While this playbook is functional, it's not pretty.***

Do you mind to change it to Ansible [`uri` module – Interacts with webservices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html) then?

> ***... it prints all output ...***

Right, that's the standard behavior of `loop`. I assume you are looking additionally for [Limiting loop output with `label`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables).

You may have a look into the following minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    PAGES:
      - host: example.com
        port: 443
        endpoint:
      - host: iana.org
        port: 443
        endpoint: help/example-domains

  tasks:

  - name: Show URL
    debug:
      msg: "url: https://{{ item.host }}:{{ item.port }}/{{ item.endpoint }}"
    loop: "{{ PAGES }}"

  - name: Get URI
    uri:
      url: "https://{{ item.host }}:{{ item.port }}/{{ item.endpoint }}"
      method: GET
      validate_certs: true
      return_content: true
      status_code: 200,404
    register: result
    when: item.host == 'example.com'
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.host }}"
    loop: "{{ PAGES }}"

  - name: Show results
    debug:
      var: result.results
```

which will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Get URI] *************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=example.com)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=iana.org)
```

or if set in `ansible.cfg`

```ini
[defaults]
display_skipped_hosts   = False
```

in only

```yaml
TASK [Get URI] **********************
ok: [localhost] => (item=example.com)
```